# Does Catholicism teach that the Pope is God?

Tags: catholicism, papacy

I am non-denominational. I have a couple Catholic friends and one of them told me that the Pope *is* God. Remembering what I heard about the Catholic religion, I corrected him and said that he was at most merely God's representative, and at least a fellow believer. My friend told me again the Pope *is* God, so this made me slightly confused. As I remember, Catholics believe the Pope is just God's representative on Earth. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've edited this down to one question. Your secondary question would make a good question here too, but we really want to keep question scopes to a manageable level so one question at a time please. You can certainly go ahead and ask that question as well.

Comment: cf. [Pope | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12260a.htm) and [Pope Titles | New Advent](https://www.ewtn.com/jp2/papal3/titles.htm): *None of these titles are titles of God*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your friend is confused. Very confused. The Pope is not God according to any official Catholic teaching.

Catholics believe a lot of things about the Pope including his ability so speak infallibly (see [ex cathedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_infallibility#Ex_cathedra)) and that his role is that of an authoritative representative of God (see [vicar of Christ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicar_of_Christ)). They believe a lot of things about the Pope that Protestants and others disagree with, but they do not believe he is God. Official doctrinal statements do not include such a thing and historically they never have.

Answer (score 5):

The pope is not God, and the Catholic Church does not teach that he is, only that he represents God on earth. However, your friend may have learnt this from the history of Pope Alexander VI, arguably one of the worst of the popes. Russel Chamberlin, in *The Bad Popes,* page 173, says that at his coronation, Pope Alexander VI (Rodrigo Borgio) committed the blasphemy of having triumphal arches proclaim: "Rome was great under Caesar but even greater far under Alexander.  The first was only a mortal – the second is a God."

Comment: Even the absurdity of saying the Pope is "a God" seems to stop considerably short of saying dogmatically "the Pope is God".

Comment: Yeah, even in Latin, there would be ambiguity, since Latin lacks a definite article. In other words, there'd be no way for us to know if he meant "a god" or "God" (the [one true] god). Catholics generally believe in deification, which means we become gods. So, it wouldn't have been blasphemous for Pope Alexander VI to have said, "I am a god." Even the psalmist called the judges of Israel "gods" (Psa. 82:1).

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 I agree about the ambiguity in Latin.  As for Psalm 82:1: "(NAB) God takes a stand in the divine council, gives judgment in the midst of the gods." Many biblical scholars see "divine council" and "gods" as references to early Israelite polytheism (which is now well-attested), not to the Judges on earth.

Comment: @DickHarfield: See Exo. 21:6, 22:8-9.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Yes. 21:6 = "to the gods" or "to God," an occasional ambiguity in Hebrew. Incidentally, Chamberlin did not say whether Alexander used 'deus' or 'divus' in his triumphal arches. I have assumed he used 'divus', which could never be a claim to be the Christian God, regardless of article. Deus could be ambiguous but would probably be seen as claiming to be the God.

Comment: @DickHarfield: Whenever אֱלֹהִים or הָאֱלֹהִים is referring to God Almighty, it would be followed by a verb conjugated in the singular number. For example, Gen. 1:1: בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים, "In the beginning God created." בָּרָא is conjugated in the singular number, as opposed to בָּרְאוּ which is conjugated in the plural number. In Exo. 22:9, the verb יַרְשִׁיעֻן is conjugated in the plural number, which means that הָאֱלֹהִים is not God Almighty (singular subject), but human judge**s** (plural subject).

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Yes, I well understand the rules by which 'elohim refers to God or gods. I thought you intended to bring my attention to another example of this, following our earlier exchange and I did not check the Hebrew (not that I have more than a few words in latin script). I disagree that whenever 'elohim does not refer to God it therefore refers to 'judges'. Please allow me to say without intended offence that I think that is a workaround by which Judaism avoids facing up to its polytheistic past. As U intend to be baptised, look at the NAB Bible Exo 21:6.

Comment: @DickHarfield: "I disagree that whenever 'elohim does not refer to God it therefore refers to 'judges'." --- I don't recall saying that. Did I? Maybe I did. I don't recall though.

Comment: @DickHarfield As far as a history book and most of the Bible says, Judaism is and always was monotheistic as a religion. God's people 'Israel' often turned against him and worshiped pagan god's and he punished them. I believe you meant Israelis or a similar noun because otherwise using 'Jews' would infer to the religion having a polytheistic past :)

Comment: the religion did have polytheistic henotheistic past

Comment: There was a lot of bad spin whirling around Alexander VI's pontificate, seeing as he was a Spaniard Pope at a time when Spain was very ill-thought of in Italy. So please take any tales you hear from him (like him bedding his own mother, and such) with a large grain of salt.

Answer (score -4):

“To make war against the Pope is to make war against God, seeing the Pope is God, and God is the Pope.” -Moreri's History. (Louis Moréri (25 March 1643 – 10 July 1680) was a French priest and encyclopedist.)

"The leader of the Catholic church is defined by the faith as the Vicar of Jesus Christ (and is accepted as such by believers). The Pope is considered the man on earth who takes the place of the Second Person of the omnipotent God of the Trinity." (John Paul II, Crossing the Threshold of Hope, p. 3, 1994).

"The Pope is not simply the representative of Jesus Christ. On the contrary, he is Jesus Christ Himself, under the veil of the flesh, and who by means of a being common to humanity continues His ministry amongst men ... Does the Pope speak? It is Jesus Christ Who is speaking. Does he teach? It is Jesus Christ Who teaches. Does he confer grace or pronounce an anathema? It is Jesus Christ Himself Who is pronouncing the anathema and conferring the grace. Hence consequently, when one speaks of the Pope, it is not necessary to examine, but to obey: there must be no limiting the bounds of the command, in order to suit the purpose of the individual whose obedience is demanded: there must be no caviling at the declared will of the Pope, and so invest it with quite another than that which he has put upon it: no preconceived opinions must be brought to bear upon it: no rights must be set up against the rights of the Holy Father  to teach and command; his decisions are not to be criticized, or his ordinances disputed. Therefore by Divine ordination, all, no matter how august the person may be — whether he wear a crown or be invested with the purple, or be clothed in the sacred vestments: all must be subject to Him Who has had all things put under Him." -Evangelical Christendom, January 1, 1895,  pg. 15, published in London by J. S. Phillips.

Comment: While that was an interesting opinion, I don't think this squares with the official teaching of the Catholic Church, and certainly not currently.  The matter of infallibility was addressed in 1870-71, Vatican I, and does not square with what is offered in this answer's third citation.   Moreri's opinion is certainly of interest, from a historical viewpoint.  The JP II citation is not consistent with the other two, in that [the vicar of Christ is the representative of Christ rather than Christ himself](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15403b.htm).